# Nvidia drivers: Errors were encountered while processing: libglx-mesa0:i386

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, 20.04, dpkg

I am trying to install `nvidia driver 460` on my `Ubuntu 20.04` laptop, but I am getting the error below.

Could anybody help me with troubleshooting it? I purged the drivers and tried different versions but I am always ending up with this error (I need at least version 418 because it's the minimum requirement for handbrake's GPU support).

```
user@pc:~$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-460 is already the newest version (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglx-mesa0:i386:
 libglx-mesa0:i386 depends on libgl1-mesa-dri; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libglx-mesa0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglx0:i386:
 libglx0:i386 depends on libglx-mesa0; however:
  Package libglx-mesa0:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglx0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1:i386:
 libgl1:i386 depends on libglx0 (= 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1); however:
  Package libglx0:i386 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup er
ror from a previous failure.
                            No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is rea
ched already
            dpkg: error processing package libgl1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386:
 libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 depends on libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386:
 libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 depends on libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglx-mesa0:i386
 libglx0:i386
 libgl1:i386
 libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386
 libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure maybe it is because of kernel version. After recent kernel update I had also this kind of problem but downgrading to older kernel versions solved problem

Comment: Thanks. Which kernel version works for you on 20.04?

Comment: Here's a good explanation to [update kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198003/set-default-kernel-in-grub). In my case downgrading to 5.4.48 solved problem. Just give it a try hope it helps :). And [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) are all kernel versions that you can download